# Datawedge Error during the scan with Motorola MC3100

Tags: attributes, device, motorola, datawedge, rsm

`Has anyone seen the following error in Datawedge 3.2.4:

Error  : Scanner : SCN1: Failed to get supported RSM attribute count. Error=a0000012
Error  : Scanner : SCN1: Scanning failed. Error : a000001d .

If so do you know the cause or fix?`

Comment: That is a strange error, RSM (Remote Scanner Management) is used for Bluetooth scanners, perhaps ensure that DataWedge is configured with the internal scanner as the default.  It is strange to be raising an RSM error on SCN1 as this is the internal scanner.  This is a pretty old device / DW version - when did this issue first occur?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your scanner is trying to connect by wireless or Bluetooth to a nearby network. Finale Data Collector operates in disconnected mode, so you don't need any wireless communication on the scanner. You can turn off the scanner's wireless modes to eliminate any pauses from the start menu or Windows icon on the task bar: Settings > Connections > Wireless manager.

If Finale has crashed or if some other software running on the scanner has crashed, you can do a warm reboot on the scanner by pressing and holding the red on/off button for 10 seconds. The button is in the upper right of Motorola MC70 scanners. A warm reboot will recover from any crashed applications and will not erase your hard drive or lose any data.

There is other scenarios to what you are experiencing

**A. Scenario #1**

The DataWedge may have become corrupted and needs to be reinstalled. The dataWedge is an application that allows to send scanned data from the barcode scanner to the any Finale application you have running on the scanner.

1. Download [datawedge.CAB](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/utilities/datawedge-toolkit.html) (you will need to have a Zebra free account)
2. You must have, or, order your Docking Station Kit (Chargers/Cradles/Docks in the Enterprise Scanning industry are SKU's sold separately, by factory protocol). Plug it into the wall, and, into your Windows 7(preferable) PC USB Port with mini USB-to-USB Communication Cable.
3. With your MCxx powered on and PC on the internet, dock your MCxx into the cradle and allow the USB drivers to sync with the computer for approximately 10 minutes - this allows your PC's "Windows Mobile Device Center" sync program to auto-install on your PC. This program allows you to view and transfer programs, files, and updates from your Computer to your handheld.
4. With your MCxx connected to Windows Mobile Device Center, hold you mouse over File Management and then click "Browse the contents of your device". Once your device window is open, drag-and-drop or copy-and-paste the DataWedge.CAB file into the window, to paste onto the unit.
5. Once DataWedge.CAB file is pasted onto the unit, the revert over to the MC70 touch-screen. From the docked MCxx, click the Windows Start Icon, then click programs, then click File Explorer. Within Windows File Explorer click the top-left dropdown arrow in the grey takbar to select My Device. There you will find the DataWedge.CAB file that you pasted. Click that file to run the installer. A Selection Screen pops up of where to install, and you must Select "Application" to install Data Wedge onto the MC70, click install. Once installation is finished, allow program a minute to initialize then Start Scanning.

**B. Scenario #2** - The default baud rate for the scanner needs to be increased.

1. Open Data Wedge (by clicking icon in toolbar tray on bottom-right of device homescreen > Advanced Configuration > Profiles > Profile0 > Input > Serial > COM 1 > Port Settings > Baud Rate > 115200 > Back

You will want to change the Baud Rates on ports : COM 1 / COM 3 / COM 7 / COM 8.

2. Once Complete, Keep Clicking Back until datawedge reports that all changes are saved.

Finlay, if none of the above works it might be very helpful to have another Windows mobile that actually works
you can launch the command "System Info" on the command prompt of both of your Windows mobile terminals (the one that work and the one that doesn't) then compare the diferences on the settings